# Preprocessing raw data in Machine Learning using Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a raw dataset with 9 features [numerical] and the 10th column is a categorical [country = france, germany, india, china, mexico]. the dataset has 20000 rows. Many of the numerical feature columns have missing data and they are not in scale. I am supposed to predict a feature value which lies in the 5th column position in the dataset.

How should I approach it?

Should I :

1. Preprocess the entire raw dataset with Imputer (for missing
   data), Encoder for categorical and Feature scale.
2. Split the preprocessed data in training and test set.

Or it would be other way around:

1. Split the raw data in to training and test set
2. Preprocess the training set only.

Reason I am confused: Once I preprocess the raw dataset, the categorical columns would explode into 5 new columns. So how do I  snip out the independent and dependent variable(5th column) out of this dataset to produce x and y array respectively, which I can split to `x_train`, `x_test`, `y_train`, `y_test` in this formula:

```
 from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
 x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = 
 train_test_split(x,y,test_size=1/3,random_state=0)
```

Comment: All your data, for training or for test should be processed in the same way. Doing machine learning you train a model to received a specific type (or scaled) input to get a wanted output. so your data to test (or to use the trained model) should be the same type (or in the same scale) than data used to train the model. you can process everything and then split or you can split the data set and then process both group with the same method...

Comment: Thanks for your response. This helps. 

Would you suggest that I move the dependent variable (5th column in this case) as the last column of the dataset before the preprocessing step? In  doing that, I would have better control on the variables. Since once I do the categorical variable encoding, which is the last column in my dataset, it explodes to multiple columns. Then it gets confusing on how to iloc the independent variables and dependent variables. 

What do you recommend.

Comment: I disagree that you should scale and then split, see below my answer.

Comment: I agree with @Jblasco to split first and then do the processing and apply the same processing on the test. Think of how you would proceed in a real world scenario where all available data is training data and all unseen or new data is the test data. How can you process the test data together with train data in that case.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you should separate your data first, then deduce the transformation you need to apply from the training set and apply it to both training and validation/testing sets.

The reason being, if you use all data, you'll get more information than if you use only the training data set (say you measure better the mean or stddev you use to treat a column). This means you train your data with the training data set and a hint of the validating/testing data set, which is bad for the predictions you'll later draw from it. This is called data snooping or data dredging (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dredging).

Comment: I am very new to ML so learning as I am progressing. What do you think about my followup question: Would you suggest that I move the dependent variable (5th column in this case) as the last column of the dataset before the preprocessing step? In doing that, I would have better control on the variables. Since once I do the categorical variable encoding, which is the last column in my dataset, it explodes to multiple columns. Then it gets confusing on how to iloc the independent variables and dependent variables. What do you recommend

Comment: I particularly do the separation of independent and dependent variables first, then do the split, then pre-process. But that depends on the libraries you are using.

Comment: You can move the 5th column to the last or not it depends on your convenience. Make sure that you split the data set properly.  For Categorical encoding which function have you used.? I think you have used Label Encoder from scikit. If so you can use `to_categorical()` of keras to produce dummy values for training your model.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Pandas, you can pre-process the data by mentioning the column names instead of column position. By this way you do not need to worry about where your Target Variable lies in the dataset.

If you are not using Pandas, then better take the target variable out, then pre-process the dataset

For both the above methods, you can do pre-processing either with the overall dataset or after splitting them into two.